# How to change the language in Tensorflow Object Detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have been looking at a youtube tutorial of Nicholas where he had made a Sign Language Detector i am also trying to do it but i want to change the language of detection to hindi language i.e. the real time detections will be shown in hindi. can you please help me with this.

Comment: what does your research about hindi sign language say: does it use the same gestures, as ASL ? if it's exactly so, it's just a matter of exchanging the letters. if it's not, you will need to retrain it, using your own data

Comment: i have trained it with hindi language but when it comes to detection instead of words it is showing boxes. What should i do